# Set a custom sound for localNotification from NSData

Tags: ios, ios7, uilocalnotification

I need to pass a sound to localNotification. I know it's limitations and required format.
But the way of adding it it's just by getting it from file name. `UILocalNotification` has just a property ***soundName*** where it gets the sound only by its ***name*** on the **App Bundle**.

I have set a **SQLite** Database when I save sounds in blob format and get it back to `NSData`. I need to set this sound which I have and give it as a parameter to localNotification in `NSData` format.

Here is how I set up the localNotification

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH-mm";
NSDate* date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:timeToSetOff.date]];

localNotification.soundName = @"";  //Here is the line where I am having issues

[localNotification setFireDate:date];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Has anyone dealt with this before, or implemented this algorithm?

Comment: This is not possible, only sounds that are in the App Bundle can be played. There is no way to play a sound without it being in the App Bundle.

Comment: @rckoenes (I am using this for an alarm app)In foreground I can do it with AVAudioPlayer initWithContents, but the problem when I set localNotification sound, I need the name.

Comment: @EridBardhaj you just want to play a sound ?

Comment: The `soundName` property only accepts a filename of a sound in you app s bundle. So when you app is running in the foreground you will be able to play the sound with `AVplayer` or something. You can not use the `soundName` to store the name. Also saving the sound as blobs will make it harder, just save the file in the documents directory and path to that file in your SQLite database. Then je pass the path to the sound file in the `userInfo` of the notification.

Comment: @rckoenes thanks for your explanation, really nice idea. If you post this as an answer, this definitely should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `soundName` property only accepts a filename of a sound in you app s bundle. So when you app is running in the foreground you will be able to play the sound with AVplayer or something. You can not use the soundName to store the name. Also saving the sound as blobs will make it harder, just save the file in the documents directory and path to that file in your SQLite database.

Then you pass the path to the sound file in the [`userInfo`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009565-CH1-SW10) of the [`UILocalNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 2):

fire this method when you receive notification

```
-(void) playSound {
NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"soundfile" ofType:@"caf"];
SystemSoundID soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath: soundPath], &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);   }
```

Comment: I know how to play a sound on foreground, but I need the sound to UILocalNotification so it can be played also when we go on background or nonactive state